# Reading a file in a jar WEB-INF/lib instead of WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java-8

My method is as such

```
public static Stream<Path> readFolder(String path) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
{
    ClassLoader loader = FileUtil.class.getClassLoader();
    URL dir = loader.getResource(path);
    if (dir == null) return Stream.empty();
    ...

    if (dir.getProtocol().equals("jar")) 
    {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(dir.toURI(), Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
        Stream<Path> results = Files.walk(fileSystem.getPath(path), 1).filter(file -> !file.toString().equals(dir.toString()));
        fileSystem.close();
        return results;
    }

    return Stream.empty();
}
```

Running the code from a jar fails. If I just run
`Paths.get(path)` the result is `/WEB-INF/lib/Database-1.0.0.jar!/com/update/sql/`  but `fileSystem.getPath(path)` returns `com/update/sql/`.

So I think the issue might be fileSystem is having issues reading the Database-1.0.0.jar inside my Application.jar!/WEB-INF/lib directory but maybe not since Paths.get(path) finds the correct file.

My error is:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: com/update/sql/
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.getAttributes(ZipPath.java:666)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:294)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:72)
at java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3574)
at util.FileUtil.readFolder(FileUtil.java:36)
```

I've scanned other questions here on Stack but nothing has seemed to address this specific issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are closing the filesystem before the stream traversal starts, so the caller will definitely get a `java.nio.file.ClosedFileSystemException`…

Comment: @Holger ok I'll need to fix that but I haven't even been able to open the file yet.

Comment: Well, I even can’t get over `getResource` for a directory-like entry of a `jar` file. Besides, you really have a jar inside a jar file and the `FileUtil` class was loaded from the nested jar (as you are resolving the `dir` URL relative to it)? And what yo you mean with “Paths.get(path) finds the correct file”? `Paths.get(String)` only resolves in the default file system.

Comment: @Holger I don't understand everything you're asking but from what I do understand my response is that callling 'Paths.get("com/update/sql")' gives me a Path with a uri '/WEB-INF/lib/Database-1.0.0.jar!/com/update/sql/'  Which tells me that 'Paths' was able to locate the resource in my jar file.  However when I try to open in with a FileSystem the file system can't open it "NoSuchFileException".

Comment: The documentation of [`Paths.get(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) clearly says: “*…using it will imply an assumed reference to the default FileSystem and limit the utility of the calling code*”. It is not for locating resources in jar files.